# Turn off filter in QGIS Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

My attribute table (as in the attached screenshot) shows that there is only 1 element and the rest of the 26 items is filtered out. 
How can I turn off this filter?

[image: my attribute table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Query Filter which is defined directly on the layer.
It is a global filter. It filters the data at the moment it enters QGIS and therefore applies to everything, including the attribute table.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html

Answer (score 2):

Might potentially be just the view you are using, if you see bottom righthand corner, change view to table view, or de-select the element that is highlighted? Maybe helps?

Answer (score 0):

go to the expression editor. delete your filter expression and replace it with "id".